# Laravel search-filter

Tags: laravel, crud

I have a problem with passing the selected index to my controller via click.
If I manually change the index in the browser, it is working.
(http://localhost:3000/admin/users?user=&sortBy=**5**)
$sortOptions is the name of my 2d array in my controller.
sortDisplay is a field in my 2d array in my controller.

Am I missing something in my foreach loop?

```
<label for="sortBy">Sort by</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="sortBy" id="sortBy">
                @foreach($sortOptions as $index => $sortOptions)
                    <option value="{{$index}}" {{ (request()->sortBy == $index ? 'selected' : '') }}>
                        {{$sortOptions["sortDisplay"]}}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to submit form when value changed
So your page will refresh and you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

In the `foreach` loop, you are assigning the same variable name as the variable you are iterating. In your case, after the first loop, you re-instantiate the `$sortOptions` variable with the content of the first index of `$sortOptions`.

```
@foreach($sortOptions as $index => $sortOption) // <-- $sortOption, not $sortOption(s)
    <option value="{{$index}}" {{ (request()->sortBy == $index ? 'selected' : '') }}>
        {{ $sortOption["sortDisplay"] }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything when I change it.

Comment: Ok, but pay attention to the side effects your variable name can make.